# Set DropDownList's SelectValue based on Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, selectedvalue

I have a DropDownList in a GridView and I am wanting to have the selected value be whatever the value for that particular person is in the database

My ASP Code for the DropDownList:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTeam" runat="server" 
                   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Team" 
                        DataValueField="Team" ondatabound="ddlTeam_DataBound">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Team] FROM [Team_Names]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

My ddlTeam_OnBound:

```
protected void ddlTeam_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
            {
                if (item.Text == "valor")
                {
                    item.Text = "Team Valor";
                }
                else if (item.Text == "mystic")
                {
                    item.Text = "Team Mystic";
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE - No Error but DDL is empty:

```
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                string query2 = "SELECT team_name FROM sec WHERE job = " + TextBox1.Text;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                        while(read.Read())
                        {
                            ddl.SelectedValue = read["team_name"].ToString();
                        }
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing the SqlCommand or opening a SqlConnection. You should put your input into a parameter to prevent a potential SQL Injection attack.

As an example:

```
            string teamName = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string query = "SELECT DISTINCT team_name FROM sec WHERE job = @job";
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@job",
                    Value = TextBox1.Text
                };

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        teamName = reader.GetString(0);
                        // or
                        int ord = reader.GetOrdinal("team_name");
                        teamName = reader.GetString(ord); // Handles nulls and empty strings.
                    }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**

You also have to set up your drop down list correctly.

```
 DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
 ddl.DataSource = // call your database code - see above
 ddl.DataValueField = "ValueProperty";
 ddl.DataTextField = "TextProperty";
 ddl.DataBind();

 ddl.SelectedValue = teamName;
```

Comment: Sorry I have all of that - I just omitted for simplicity - my problem is that I'm pulling the ddl items from one table and need to get the initial selected value from another table.

Comment: Ok, your original question was a bit confusing. So is your question that you want to populate one DropDownList based on another DropDownList selected value from the database?

Comment: No I am populating a list from one table (team_names) but I want the initial selectedvalue to come from another table (sec).

Comment: Ok, so make a database call to get the value you want and set the initial value of the dropdownlist.

Comment: Updated my answer - still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in read["job_role_code"].ToString()? Also, you don't need to explicitly close the reader as its in a using block.

Comment: I don't think so. It says "Enumeration yielded no results" in debug mode.

Comment: Is there anything in TextBox1.Text? Does that query return any results when you run it against the database?

Comment: Yes there is something in the textbox and yes it does

Comment: I've edited my answer. Use a variable to see if any value is there - see my code.

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in a query in `SqlDataSource` and don't use code behind without necessity.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTeam" runat="server" 
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Team_txt" 
            DataValueField="Team"><%--No need  ondatabound="ddlTeam_DataBound"--%>
        </asp:DropDownList><%--datasourceId must match --%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Team],case Team when 'valor' then 'Team Valor' when 'mystic' then 'Team Mystic' else Team end team_txt FROM [Team_Names]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need the entire list of team names to display with the selectedvalue being the current value associated with that person in the database

Comment: OK. return `ddlTeam_DataBound` to the code and set `.SelectedValue` in it. But nothing more.

Comment: I can't do it in the DataBound method because it's dependent on a TextBox entry. What I did was put the code that's in the updated section above in the TextChanged method but it's not working

Comment: In OP ddl source doesn't depend on any parameters. You also can set SelectedValue in `GridView_ItemDataBound` handler. DDL is empty because you set `DataSourceID=srs1` and the `sqldatasource` has `id=src2`